# Dice jQuery - random # + replace the text on die

Tags: javascript, jquery

My very first question. I have a feeling this is something simple, but it's been driving me crazy because I can't find the issue. I've tested the math function with an alert, so I can see that is working but the actual jQuery below doesn't seem to be running to swap the text. Please help!

```
var dice = 1;
function math(sides){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*sides)+1).toString();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var dice = math(6);
        alert("Dice now at " + dice);
        $("#number").text("dice");
    });
});
```

Comment: You put quotes to the dice in text function. However, dice is a variable, just remove quoutes and everything will work/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dice is a variable, so remove quotes

Try this

```
$("#number").text(dice);  // This will replace the current text with new
```

If `#number` is text box

```
$("#number").val(dice); // This will replace the current value with new
```

Comment: +1 what is #number is a `textbox`?? then it must be `$("#number").val(dice);`

Comment: Thank you. I've tried both versions and still not working :-/ 

`$("#number").text(dice);`

`$("#number").val(dice);`

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the `$(document).ready(function(){` is not working. I have no idea why? I tried to test the following simple alert and it's not working: 



`<script type="text/javascript" src="dice.js"></script>
<script text="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("jQuery is working");
});
</script>`

Comment: Problem solved! This worked, just turns out the link I had to the google jQuery library was bad.